# PHP INSERT into creates Database error

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am attempting to create a function that will insert items (and will do the same to edit) items in a database through a form. I have the form and the PHP - and when I run the function, I get the correct database name to pull and the variable names to pull along with the values I input, but I then see a database error? Any help would be great (I'm still newer to PHP really and pulling out some hair)

Config File:

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'DEFINED';
$password = 'DEFINED';
$database = 'DEFINED';
$table = 'recipes';

require('../config.php');  
$link = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database,$link);

/* Get values and submit */
$rid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rid']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
$tags = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tags']);
$search_tags = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_tags']);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$description2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description2']);
$recipeAbout = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['recipeAbout']);
$ingredients_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ingredients_1']);
$directions_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['directions_1']);

$query = "INSERT INTO $table (name, category, tags, search_tags, description,description2, recipeAbout, ingredients_1,directions_1) VALUES ('$name','$category','$description','$description2' $tags','$search_tags','$description','$recipeAbout','$ingredients_1','$directions_1')";

echo $query;
```

Comment: I don't see a declaration of $table?  do you set the value `$table = 'TABLE_NAME_GOES_HERE'`

Comment: I have it set it my config file.

Comment: What database error does it give you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the missing comma in `'$description2' $tags'` => `'$description2', $tags'` which you said had been added afterwards, and signaled by Ryan: there's also a missing quote, so change it to  `'$description2', '$tags'` and having 2x `'$description'` variables, remove one.

```
VALUES 
('$name','$category','$tags','$description','$description2', '$search_tags','$recipeAbout','$ingredients_1','$directions_1')";
```

However, the most important part to querying, is that you must use `mysql_query()` which you are not using => [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) which is why data isn't being inserted, once you've fixed the syntax errors.

- `mysql_query()` is the essential part.

Add the following to your code:

```
if(mysql_query($sql,$link)){
echo "Success";
}

else{
echo "Error" . mysql_error();
}
```

Plus, use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

- You're using a deprecated library and open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)..

Plus make sure you have assigned `$table` to the table you wish to enter data into. It's not shown in your question.

You also did not show what your HTML form contains. Make sure that you are using a POST method and that all elements are named with no typos.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**EDIT**: and using `mysqli_`

As a quick test, try the following and replacing the values in the line below with your own.

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database") 

or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

$table = "recipes";

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `$table` (`name`) VALUES ('".$name."')")

or die(mysqli_error($link));

?>
```

If that still does not work, then you need to check your database, table, column name(s), including types and column lengths.

Answer (score 3):

Lot's of stuff wrong here...

1. You're missing a quote on the second of these two items, as well as either a string concat or a comma: `'$description2' $tags'`
2. You've also got your order messed up for tags, search tags, and description 1/2.
3. `$description` is in there twice (you have 9 columns defined and 10 values in your statement)
4. You don't seem to have declared a value for `$table`
5. As Fred -ii- has pointed out in his answer, you're missing `mysql_query()` to actually run it. I assumed you have it further down in your code, but it's missing from the post, which is causing some confusion...

Also, consider updating to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` functions.

Comment: I added the comma, and updated to `mysqli` for all and still get a database error.

Comment: OP also had a missing quote `'$description2' $tags'` => `'$description2', '$tags'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yep, caught that too. It's the first bullet point. :)

Comment: My bad, I'm more of "graphical person" lol. +1 ;) good catch, as outlined in my answer, kudos to you Ryan.

Comment: @Fred-ii- much appreciated, good catch on the query. That should have been more obvious to me...

Comment: You're welcome Ryan. I'm hoping this one will be resolved and soon. OP says that the connection/login is being denied. This may be a long night lol

Answer (score 0):

what are you echoing $query for?
You do not have any reason to do that except if you just want to use it as a string variable.

it should be mysql_query($query);

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact "database error" error you are getting?

- I suggest reading [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) article about PDO
- If you can't insert the data correctly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) might be your problem too.